# Почему этот код работает так?

Tags: строки, swift

```
var str:NSString = "somesjhgbjkl"
let str2 = str
str = "g" as NSString
print(str2)
```

этот код должен печатать "g", однако выдает "somesjhgbjkl". Почему так происходит?

Comment: А почему вы считаете что должно происходить иначе? https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/StringsAndCharacters.html#ID289

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вам уже указали в комментарии, строки в свифт при присвоении копируются, а не создается ссылка на строку, поэтому в результате получаются две независимые строки